# Progressbar in Jquery-UI - Javascript

Tags: jquery, progress-bar, formula

I am trying to update a progressbar based one two variables:

- Start the bar at 'x' procent
- 'x' Minutes to go untill 100%

( http://jqueryui.com/demos/progressbar/ )

So far I have this:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    var pGress = setInterval(function() {
        var pVal = $('#progressbar').progressbar('option', 'value');
        var pCnt = !isNaN(pVal) ? (pVal + 1) : <?php echo $procent_finished; ?>;
        if (pCnt > 100) {
            clearInterval(pGress);
        } else {
            $('#progressbar').progressbar({value: pCnt});
            $('#progressbar1').progressbar({value: pCnt});
        }
    },<?php echo $remaining_minutes; ?>);
});
</script>
```

"$procent_finished" is the % already done  and "$remaining_minutes" should be the remaining minutes to 100%.

**Example:**

I want the bar to start at 60% and 1 minute to reach 100%.

- procent_finished = 60
- remaining_minutes = 600 (10minutes = 1*6*10 if I'm right..)

But when I run the file with these variables it starts indeed on 60%, but it's already finished to 100% after 25 seconds. (while it should only be completed to 100% after 1 minute)

I have tried and searched for several formulas to get the correct remaining time, but I really can't seem to figure it out. Hopefully there's anyone who can help me out, because I have no clue anymore.

Thanks in advance!

edit: it would be even better if it updates the progressbar every minute and it will just adds the amount of %.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setInterval needs an interval in milliseconds, you are setting an interval of 600, which is 0.6 seconds. 1 minute would be 60000.

So to have a function update the bars every minute you would do this,

```
$(function() {
var percentDone = <?php echo $procent_finished; ?>;
var minute = 0;
var percentIntervals = (100 - percentDone )/<?php echo $remaining_minutes; ?>;

$('#progressbar').progressbar({value: percentDone});

var pGress = setInterval(function() {
    var nVal = (percentIntervals) * (++minute) + percentDone;
    if (nVal > 100) {
        clearInterval(pGress);
    } else {
        $('#progressbar, #progressbar1').progressbar({value: nVal});
    }
}, 60000);
});
```

where `remaining_minutes` is an integer representing how many minutes are left.

http://jsfiddle.net/q4WqL/

Comment: I have found one problem though. When I use these variables the progressbar is sometimes a bit further when you open the page in a second tab/window. (and refreshes this new page some later than the page that's already open) I think this can happen when the $remaining_minutes or $procent_finished are just changing from value when you load the page. Any thoughts for a possible solution? (the weird thing is that the progressbars do reach 100% at the same time, even when one started later)I changed the interval to '1000' though, and using $remaining_seconds instead of $remaining_minutes.

Comment: @user985911 I'm not sure what the problem is, that is supposed to happen. You are saying that when you load the page with different starting values it acts different?

Comment: It was my own fault. (was rounding the variables on the minute, where i should've used seconds instead) Thanks again for your contribution.